# Is it possible to prevent an installation of an app in android?

Tags: android, installation

This should be done  by a security-app, which thinks that the user installs malicious code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are wanting to write an app to do this since you're posting in a programming website. However, your question is so vague that I'm not sure what part you're having trouble with.

There are several apps that do this already if that's what you're looking for... https://play.google.com/store/search?q=antivirus&c=apps